# Pandas how to find consecutive value increase over time on time series data

Tags: pandas, function, time-series

I have a dataframe with three columns (tilted as name, value, date)as below:

| Tool | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 52.14 | 1/1 |
| A | 51.5 | 1/7 |
| A | 52 | 1/10 |
| A | 52.9 | 2/1 |
| B | 53.1 | 1/5 |
| B | 51.7 | 1/10 |
| B | 51.9 | 1/21 |
| B | 52.4 | 1/22 |
| B | 53.0 | 2/1 |
| B | 51.5 | 2/15 |

I would like to find which tools have increased measure values on three measurement days.

Tool B's value has increased on 1/21 and then increased on 1/22 and then increased on 2/1. so the outcome will be as below:

| Tool | Value | Date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | 51.7 | 1/10 |
| B | 51.9 | 1/21 |
| B | 52.4 | 1/22 |
| B | 53.0 | 2/1 |

I am wondering how can I define a function in pandas to give the desired result.
Thanks.

Comment: Tool A increased from `1/7` to `1/10` to `2/1`, should that be part of your desired result as well?

Comment: @mitoRibo  No. Just looking for consecutive increases, meaning need to sort dates for each tool,  and then determine the tools that have increased values on three consecutive measurement days.

Answer (score 0):

You can first sort everything according to "tool" and "date"

```py
df = df.sort_values(by=["tool", "date"])
```

Then, you can use the [`shift()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) on "Value" to add another column which contains the "Value" from the day before.

```py
df["value_minus_1"] = df["Value"].shift()
```

This gives you a column which contains the measurement of the previous day. Then, you can use `shift(2)` to get the measurements of two days ago.

```py
df["value_minus_2"] = df["Value"].shift(2)
```

Finally, you can drop the rows that have `na`s and filter the rows:

```py
df = df.dropna()
df = df[df.val > df.value_minus_1]
df = df[df.value_minus_1 > df.value_minus_2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer, but I bet there is a better one. I make new Series to keep track of whether a value is less than the next (`increasing`), increasing 'runs' as groups (`increase_group`) and then how many consecutive increases happen in that group (`consec_increases`). I've kept these as stand-alone Series, but if you add them as columns to your table you can see the reasoning. Getting the `2/1` row added is a bit hacked together because it's not part of the same `increase_group` and I can't figure that out in a more clever way than just adding one more index past the group max

```
  Tool  Value  Date  increasing  increase_group  consec_increases
0    A  52.14   1/1       False               1                 0
1    A  51.50   1/7        True               2                 2
2    A  52.00  1/10        True               2                 2
3    A  52.90   2/1       False               3                 0
4    B  53.10   1/5       False               4                 0
5    B  51.70  1/10        True               5                 3
6    B  51.90  1/21        True               5                 3
7    B  52.40  1/22        True               5                 3
8    B  53.00   2/1       False               6                 0
9    B  51.50  2/15       False               6                 0
```

Here's the actual code

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Tool': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'Value': [52.14, 51.5, 52.0, 52.9, 53.1, 51.7, 51.9, 52.4, 53.0, 51.5],
    'Date': ['1/1','1/7','1/10','2/1','1/5','1/10','1/21','1/22','2/1','2/15'],
})

#Assuming your table is already sorted by Tool then by Date like your example

#Bool Series that is True if the prev Tool value is lt (<) the next (increasing) 
increasing = df['Value'].lt(df.groupby('Tool')['Value'].shift(-1))
#df['increasing'] = increasing #uncomment if you want to see what's happening

#Group the rows by increasing 'runs'
increase_group = increasing.groupby(df['Tool'], group_keys=False).apply(lambda v: v.ne(v.shift(1))).cumsum()
#df['increase_group'] = increase_group #uncomment if you want to see what's happening

#Count the number of consecutive increases per group
consec_increases = increasing.groupby(increase_group).transform(lambda v: v.cumsum().max())
#df['consec_increases'] = consec_increases #uncomment if you want to see what's happening

#print(df) #uncomment if you want to see what's happening

#get the row indices of each group w/ 3 or more consec increases 
inds_per_group = (
    increase_group[consec_increases >= 3] #this is where you can set the threshold
        .groupby(increase_group)
        .apply(lambda g: list(g.index)+[max(g.index)+1]) #get all the row inds AND one more
)

#use the row indices to get the output table
out_df = pd.concat(df.loc[inds].assign(group=i) for i,inds in enumerate(inds_per_group))
```

With output:

```
  Tool  Value  Date  group
5    B   51.7  1/10      0
6    B   51.9  1/21      0
7    B   52.4  1/22      0
8    B   53.0   2/1      0
```

The reason I've added a `group` column is to help you distinguish when you have multiple consecutive runs of 3 or more. For example if your original table had 50.14 instead of 52.14 for the first value:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Tool': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'],
    'Value': [50.14, 51.5, 52.0, 52.9, 53.1, 51.7, 51.9, 52.4, 53.0, 51.5],
    'Date': ['1/1','1/7','1/10','2/1','1/5','1/10','1/21','1/22','2/1','2/15'],
})
```

Then the output is

```
  Tool  Value  Date  group
0    A  50.14   1/1      0
1    A  51.50   1/7      0
2    A  52.00  1/10      0
3    A  52.90   2/1      0
5    B  51.70  1/10      1
6    B  51.90  1/21      1
7    B  52.40  1/22      1
8    B  53.00   2/1      1
```

Comment: thanks a lot. this is a very clever answer @mitoRibo . the last line of code doesn't work for me. i am wondering what's wrong.

Comment: @Soodi it works for me, can you tell me what doesn't work for you? Do you get an error or is the result incorrect? does the example dataframe that I included work?